# no database found when running lein migration

Tags: sqlite, clojure, migration, luminus

I am uisng luminus to build a webpage with sqlite. When I try to migrate (lein run migrate) I get the following message:

```
batch entry 0: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "auto_increment": syntax error)
```

my dev-config.edn:

```
;; WARNING
;; The dev-config.edn file is used for local environment variables, such as database credentials.
;; This file is listed in .gitignore and will be excluded from version control by Git.

{:dev true
 :port 3000
 ;; when :nrepl-port is set the application starts the nREPL server on load
 :nrepl-port 7000
 
 :database-url "jdbc:sqlite:kammem_dev.db"}
```

and my migration file:

```
create table adress
(id integer primary key auto_increment,
gata varchar(30),
nummer integer,
stad varchar(30),
postn integer,
land varchar(30));

create table foreningar
(id integer promary key auto_increment,
namn varchar(30),
ordf varchar(30),
kassor varchar(30),
resten varchar(30));

create table forbund
(id integer promary key auto_increment,
namn varchar(30));
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Its [autoincrement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm) - no underscore

Comment: accoring to the documentation it is underscore: https://luminusweb.com/docs/guestbook#creating_the_database

Comment: The documentation was not written with sqlite in mind, but rather with a more common solution, e.g. mysql.

Comment: ah, ok. .now I can migrate, removing the underscore, but it is just migrating one table, the first one, "adress". is it one table per file?